# How to substitute Binary values with Yes/ No in R Dataframe

Tags: r, string, replace, binary, numeric

I have the following dataframe

```
edge    Phone   new buy
 0        0      0   1
 0        0      0   1
 0        0      0   1
 0        0      0   1
```

I wish to replace the ones with "yes" and Two's's with No.
I have tried the following

```
  DF[,1:4][DF[,1:4]==0]<-'NO'
```

That does not work.

Comment: additionally to answers in the duplicate link you can do : `DF$buy <- c('no','yes') [DF$buy + 1]`

Comment: for all columns : `sapply(DF,function(x) c('no','yes') [x + 1])`

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper you should add that as an answer to the dupe target!

Comment: Alternatively - and potentially more flexible if you have more than 2 options - you can use the `merge()` function. Store the new column in another data frame `moreinfo <- data.frame(buy = c(1,2), buy2 = c("Yes", "No"))`. Then merge it with the original data frame: `merge(DF, moreinfo, by = "buy")`.

Comment: @Sotos I can't because the dupe is proposing the reverse transformation (yes/no to 0/1), my solution doesn't really suit it. Maybe you could reopen this one.

Comment: oops...@Moody_Mudskipper I added the correct dupe. You can add it there

Comment: alright, done :)